# Persisting dynamic groovy properties with GORM MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails, dynamic, properties, groovy

I am currently trying to persist the following class with the GORM MongoDB plugin for grails:

```
class Result {

    String url

    def Result(){

    }


    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapWith="mongo"

    static mapping = {
        collection "results"
        database "crawl"
    }
}
```

The code I'm running to persist this class is the following:

```
class ResultIntegrationTests {

    @Before
    void setUp() {

    }

    @After
    void tearDown() {

    }

    @Test
    void testSomething() {
        Result r = new Result();

        r.setUrl("http://heise.de")

        r.getMetaClass().setProperty("title", "This is how it ends!")

        println(r.getTitle())

        r.save(flush:true)
    }
}
```

This is the result in MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong(1), "url" : "http://heise.de", "version" : 0 }#
```

Now the url is properly persisted with MongoDB but the dynamic property somehow is not seen by the mapper - although the println(r.getTitle()) works perfectly fine.

I am new to groovy so I thought that someone with a little more experience could help me out with this problem. Is there a way to make this dynamically added property visible to the mapping facility? If yes how can I do that?

Thanks a lot for any advice...

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding random properties to the metaClass and hoping that Grails will both scan the metaClass looking for your random properties and then persist them, why not just add a Map  to your domain class, (or a new Key/Value domain class which Result can `hasMany`) so you can add random extra properties to it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

try this [doc](http://springsource.github.com/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html#3.4%20Dynamic%20Attributes)

```
@Test
void testSomething() {
    Result r = new Result();

    r.url = "http://heise.de"

    r.['title'] = "This is how it ends!"  //edit: forgot the subscript 

    println r.['title']

    r.save(flush:true)
}
```

BTW, Instead of using gorm or hibernate you can always use directly java api / [gmongo](https://github.com/poiati/gmongo).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work because there is no title attribute inside the class that I can access. And as far as I can see r.title = "something" doesn't create a new attribute.

Comment: it shouldn't be `r.['title']` but `r['title']`